Getting error expected `MiniSecretKey`, found `schnorrkel::keys::MiniSecretKey`
I have a test-suite that is based on sub-xt. This is also pulled in the suite as a dependency in cargo.toml as follows.
[dependencies]
subxt = { version = "0.37.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/subxt" }

I have installed subxt using the following command.
cargo install --version 0.37.0 subxt-cli

I have my node running and then I generate the encoded metadata and the compact.compressed.wasm. I run the test-suite using the command
cargo run

I get the following error during compilation.
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> /home/rrr/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/sp-core-7.0.0/src/sr25519.rs:591:33
    |
591 |           let mini_key: MiniSecretKey = mini_secret_from_entropy(entropy, password.unwrap_or(""))
    |  _______________________-------------___^
    | |                       |
    | |                       expected due to this
592 | |             .expect("32 bytes can always build a key; qed");
    | |___________________________________________________________^ expected `MiniSecretKey`, found `schnorrkel::keys::MiniSecretKey`
    |
    = note: `schnorrkel::keys::MiniSecretKey` and `MiniSecretKey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `schnorrkel::keys::MiniSecretKey` is defined in crate `schnorrkel`
   --> /home/rrr/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/schnorrkel-0.11.4/src/keys.rs:99:1
    |
99  | pub struct MiniSecretKey(pub (crate) [u8; MINI_SECRET_KEY_LENGTH]);
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: `MiniSecretKey` is defined in crate `schnorrkel`
   --> /home/rrr/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/schnorrkel-0.9.1/src/keys.rs:99:1
    |
99  | pub struct MiniSecretKey(pub (crate) [u8; MINI_SECRET_KEY_LENGTH]);
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `schnorrkel` are being used?


My current active-tool chain is as follows.
nightly-2024-05-02-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.80.0-nightly (c987ad527 2024-05-01)

while my node is using an older nightly toolchain
nightly-2022-10-09-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustc 1.66.0-nightly (8796e7a9c 2022-10-08)

How do I fix this to run the test-suite?

Your error message mostly explains the issue here:

note: perhaps two different versions of crate schnorrkel are being used?

The error you're having is that something is expecting the MiniSecretKey from schnorrkel 0.9.1, but is being given a MiniSecretKey from schnorrkel 0.11.4.
subxt-signer is using schnorrkel 0.11.4, and sp-core 7.0.0 (which is quite old now and was published Nov 16th 2022) asks for schnorrkel 0.9.1 (well 0.9.1 <= n < 0.10.0).
If possible, one solution is to update sp-core to a more recent version (34.0.0 is the latest at the time of writing and asks for 0.11.4, so that would work).
If you're passing a MiniSecretKey from sp-core to subxt-signer, another solution is to manually import the newer version of schnorrkel and manually convert form the old MiniSecretKey to the new one.

I think sp-core is not a direct dependency. I updated other dependencies to their latest versions. I am getting a different error now. Like follows
error: Failed to fetch metadata, make sure that you're pointing at a node that is providing substrate-based metadata: Cannot scale encode/decode value: Cannot try_into() to Metadata.
--> src/main.rs:21:1
|
21 | #[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "./data/metadata.scale")]

One reason might be that my node points to an older substrate release branch. I was trying older subtxt version 0.25.0 but whenever I run the test suite I just get the following error.
Updating crates.io index
Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/subxt`

error: failed to select a version for the requirement subxt = "^0.25.0"
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.37.0
location searched: Git repository https://github.com/paritytech/subxt

RE "failed to select a version for the requirement subxt": if you point to a git dependency like that, you'd need to use tag = "v0.25.0" to point at the relevant git commit to get an older version. RE "Failed to fetch metadata", it sounds like the "./data/metadata.scale" isn't the expected format. Have a go at using the subxt binary to fetch metadata again from a node and try that (ie https://docs.rs/subxt/latest/subxt/book/setup/codegen/index.html)

[dependencies]
subxt = {git = "https://github.com/paritytech/subxt", tag = "v0.25.0"}
tokio = { version = "1.8", features = ["rt-multi-thread", "macros", "time"] }
serde = { version = "1.0.124", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.64"
sp-core = { version = "34.0.0", default-features = false }
sp-keyring = "34.0.0"
sp-runtime = "34.0.0"
futures = "0.3.13"
codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.0.0", default-features = false, features = ["derive", "full", "bit-vec"] }
hex = "0.4.3"
tracing-subscriber = "0.3.18"
rand = "0.8.5"
These are my dependencies

If I use the tag= "v0.25.0" I get the MiniSecretKey error again even if I bump sp-core to v34.0.0. I am not sure if manually import the newer version of Schnorrkel and manually convert form the old MiniSecretKey would work as the MiniSecretkey error does not originate in my code. I feel that just using the latest version of subxt does not lead to this error but then I have to handle the next error which is the metadata error I mentioned earlier.

What specifically is the metadata error you mentioned? Updating Subxt to the latest would def be the recommendation, since you're pretty far behind at the moment!

for #[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "./data/metadata.scale")] pub mod polkadot {}
I am getting error that says
Cannot scale encode/decode value: Cannot try_into() to Metadata.

Also the metadata version is 14.

"Cannot scale encode/decode value: Cannot try_into() to Metadata." — that does very much sound like the file you're pointing to is the wrong format. Could you share the metadata file in some way?

These are the contents of metadata.scale
https://dpaste.org/rk92H

https://dpaste.com/AGCHNAMVH
And some first few 1500 lines of the same metadata in json if that works.

Re the metadata not working; the JSON version looks sane to me, so I would expect the SCALE encoded version of that to work. I'd raise an issue in the Subxt github repo with steps to reproduce (including how you create the metadata) and we can look into that!

update: I figured out a way to make subtxt-v0.25.0 work for me and successfully ran the tests.

What was the issue in the end?

So subxt-v0.25.0 was dependent on sp-core-v7.0.0. sp-core-v7.0.0 was dependent on schnorrkel-v0.9.1 and  substrate-bip39-v0.4.6.  substrate-bip39-v0.4.6 was itself dependent on schnorrkel-v0.11.4 which cause the minisecretkey error. I patched the sp-core-v0.7.0 to one that depends on substrate-bip39-v0.4.4 which used  schnorrkel-v0.9.1 and that seemed to fix the error.

Maybe I could have explicitly stated the exact substrate-bip39 in the dependencies, which might have worked, but I haven't tried that. I just patched it by giving a specific revision for sp-core ideally one that  used substrate-bip39-v0.4.4 which in turn uses schnorrkel-v0.9.1.
